# Ruby threads don't print kafka messages

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka

I need to consume some kafka messages from a topic with 6 partitions. I want to do it with threads, as such:

```
require 'poseidon'
require 'msgpack'

theads = [];

6.times do |partition|
    theads << Thread.new {
        puts "start thread #{partition}\n"
        consumer = Poseidon::PartitionConsumer.new("my_test_consumer", "localhost", 9093,
                                                   "transactions", partition, :latest_offset)
        loop do
            messages = consumer.fetch
            messages.each do |m|
                puts "partition #{partition}:\n " + MessagePack.unpack(m.value)
            end
        end
    }
end

theads.each { |thread| thread.join }
```

But when I run it and there are messages in the kafka topic (I check them with other script similar to the problem one, but without threads), they don't get printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

hm, I found the problem, but it is strange though. Because the script throw the exception after some long time delay.
I was not implicitly converting the MessagePack.unpack(m.value) to string.
So once I added a .to_s after it, it worked.

```
puts "partition #{partition}:\n " + MessagePack.unpack(m.value).to_s
```

Comment: You might need to `thread.abort_on_exception = true`. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D to get an exception in the main thread.